# Java ForkJoinPool cannot be called twice?

Tags: java, multithreading

I am writing a Java multithreading program using fork/join. When I call fork/join pool twice, it will only be executed once, why?

```
public class Test extends RecursiveAction{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test test=new Test();
        test.myCompute();
        // calling the 2nd time, no output
        test.myCompute();
    }

    public void myCompute() {
        ForkJoinPool fjPool = new ForkJoinPool();
        fjPool.invoke(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void compute() {
        System.out.println("mark");
    }

}
```

output:
mark

Comment: "I am writing a Java multithreading program using fork/join....". What is your program trying to achieve?

Comment: I want Test.compute() to be executed twice.

Comment: You want to try fork/join frame work _-or-_ you want to try a multi-threaded application?

Comment: fork/join is multithreaded. I don't see the difference. I want to use fork/join to write a program.

Comment: Here are some examples: [Example 1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/forkjoin.html) and [Example 2](https://www.baeldung.com/java-fork-join).

Comment: "Use as few thread pools as possible – in most cases, the best decision is to use one thread pool per application or system", what does this mean? from example2.

Comment: It is difficult to answer any of your questions without knowing your level of knowledge about concurrency (using Java). Also what is the application you are trying to develop? What is is the application trying to do?

Comment: I just want to know why Test.compute() cannot be executed twice. My program is a small game and is a few hundred lines, it's compute-intensive and uses fork/join to divide into smaller subtasks.

Comment: Here is another example of using [fork/join](https://homes.cs.washington.edu/~djg/teachingMaterials/spac/grossmanSPAC_forkJoinFramework.html). You could try this example and apply it in your application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you're submitting the same task instance for execution multiple times. Each instance can only be executed once (unless you use the `reinitialize()` method before submitting it again... however, you would typically just create a new task instance instead).